# Pie chart isn't loading, but the labels are

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js in Laravel to display data.

I'm following [this](https://appdividend.com/2017/07/13/add-charts-laravel-using-chartjs/) tutorial, which worked for the bar chart. But now I'm trying a pie chart.

This is my controller which gets the data.

```
public function chart()
      {
        $result = \DB::table('users')
                    ->where('userType','=','Landlord')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
                    ->get();
        return response()->json($result);
      }
```

The view is this

```
<script>
        var url = "{{url('/users')}}";
        var Name = new Array();
        var Email = new Array();
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $.get(url, function(response){
            response.forEach(function(data){
                Name.push(data.name);
                Email.push(data.email);
            });
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');

              var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx,{
                type: 'pie',

                data : {
                  datasets: [{
                      data: [Name,Email]
                }],

                // These labels appear in the legend and in the tooltips when hovering different arcs
                labels:  [Name, Email]
            }
              });

            });
          });

        </script>
```

This is the output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ChartJS documenation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html), the expected data passed for a pie chart is numbers only. Here's an example of a dataset that should work:

```
data = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [10, 20, 30]
    }],

    // These labels appear in the legend and in the tooltips when hovering different arcs
    labels: [
        'Red',
        'Yellow',
        'Blue'
    ]
};
```

Currently, your Ajax request is getting the name and email from the `/users` route; you will need to update the request to get some sort of number value from `/users` and add that to the dataset.